# Replace By Fee on Bitcoin unconfirmed transaction

Tags: bitcoin

I'm trying to Replace By Fee (RBF) an unconfirmed transaction due to low fee which was set more than a week ago ([5c5dcb0b21dc6142d789899f5efb31b2deb9366644f83d6dfa6e580f9a8697f0](https://blockchain.info/tx/5c5dcb0b21dc6142d789899f5efb31b2deb9366644f83d6dfa6e580f9a8697f0)).
To do the replacement, I'm using [coinb.in](https://coinb.in). However, when I fill in my address (1SfmVjR5itYMgFY7jD5meLg8efmmtKfXV) and hit 'Load', the tool shows a zero balance. I know it's not correct, as the transaction is not confirmed yet and as I can check the balance in [BlockCypher](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/address/1SfmVjR5itYMgFY7jD5meLg8efmmtKfXV/).
Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong?
Should I insert the Input to my wallet manually on coinb.in? If so, where can I find the 'Script'? It doesn't seem right...

Comment: Is it a programming question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no "unspent transaction output" at your Address currently so that Coinb.in shows a zero balance.

You can get a raw transaction with [here](https://blockchain.info/tx/5c5dcb0b21dc6142d789899f5efb31b2deb9366644f83d6dfa6e580f9a8697f0?format=hex).
After you get it, you can modify the amount of BTC for output with Coinb.in, sign it with your private key and broadcast it.
Hope this is helpful for you.